# Gdb in tui mode not expanding CMD window

Tags: gdb, debugging, tui

Using gdb in tui mode and I'm having a problem with the size of the work area of the CMD window.

Using the `winheight` I am able to modify the hight for the SRC and CMD windows, but the CMD window refuses to be larger than 20 lines, even if `info win` gives a size of 40+ lines.

SRC window on other hand is able to change it's size accordingly. Refreshing the screen does not help, and I'm ending up with "blank" space between the SRC and CMD windows, that should be used by the CMD window, but is not.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: This is a bug in Gdb (11400). See http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11400